# Is it possible to run and show the app on a device with snappy core?

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-core, raspberrypi

The question is as simple as show the app writen for snappy/ubuntu core on a device running snappy/ubuntu core.
Like the Raspberry Pi 2.
Is this possible or am I better off running Ubuntu Mate on the Pi 2?